# Shouldn't disable_with repopulate the button value after answer

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails

I have a form that look something like this:

```
= form_for(@user, :remote=> true, :url => @url, html: {role: :form, 'data-model' => @params_key}) do |f|
  = button_tag 'Register', class: 'btn btn-primary submit-button', type: 'submit',
                  :data => {:disable_with => 'Bamm'}
```

When I press the button it changes the text and everything, but when the rails answer the button value do not change back to 'Register'

Is this a correct behaviour?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the answer. On this [site](http://makandracards.com/makandra/3877-re-enable-submit-buttons-disabled-by-the-disable_with-option)

I created a function that is called when Ajax returns error to attach the errors to the correct fields. Inside that function I added the following call

Inside my user.coffee I have the following code:

```
$ ->
  $(document).bind('ajaxError', 'form#form_name', ( (event, jqxhr, settings, exception) ->
    $(event.data).render_form_errors( $.parseJSON(jqxhr.responseText) )
  ))

$.fn.render_form_errors = (errors) ->
  ...
  $.rails.enableFormElements($($.rails.formSubmitSelector));
  ...
```

and it will work again

Comment: Could you please add a reference where you found it, and where exactly are you adding it?

Comment: Very good! Please make your answers more descriptive next time.

Answer (score 0):

Your form has ":remote=> true" in it, so it is an ajax request. After controller action (update or create) completes, it triggers corresponding .js.erb file (update.js.erb or create.js.erb). And the JavaScript in this file defines what elements will be changed/refreshed on your page. So, it looks like your JavaScript changes "the text and everything", BUT not your form, and therefore your form still stays in the disabled mode.

Just try to remove that ":remote=> true" part from your form, and your page will be fully refreshed, and your button will become enabled again. Or add correct refresh of your form in the corresponding .js.erb file.

Comment: Maybe I did not explain myself well. when the answer come back it enables the button and I can click it, but the text do not get changed back to the text that I had before

Comment: @jpereira: Right, the disabled state is with text "Bamm" and active state is with "Register". So, since you do not refresh the form, it never happens. Button does not go to the active state without refresh.

Comment: @jpereira: sorry, you said that you can click it...? Do you see that your server log is changing after you click your button with "Bamm" on it? You are probably missing something. After your text changes from "Register" to "Bammm" it will stay this way until this form is refresh, and it is disabled, and you should not be able to click on it.

Comment: Yes it is clickable and will resend the form to the server. The only issue I am facing is the text not changing back